# mysqli line breaks

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmailer

I am not understanding how to eliminate the returns and new lines that are showing up in my emails that I am using PHPMailer.

I start with `mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['message']);`

and then I echo this in the HTML body of the email and it returns something like this:

> Hi, This is another testrnrnRandy -
>   Done

What do I need to do so that the return new line actually shows up and the rn does not?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, but [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` only to calculate values that are actually going to be used for constructing SQL queries.